# Creating and using Constructors in C# along with Boolean methods

Tags: c#, object, methods, constructor, boolean

I am having some trouble with constructors in a C# assignment. The first block of code below contains some of the instructions for the assignment. Essentially, as I understand it, I am to create two constructors, one for setting a default date, and another for checking a date from the user. Also, there is a `SetDate` method that seems to be doing the same thing. These seem redundant, yet according to the assignment instructions, both are required. I am VERY new to object-oriented programming so I am not sure how to "pass" stuff to a constructor or really how to use it and call it in the main method. The second block of code is what I have written so far. All of the date validation methods seem fine. But, I have no idea what to do with the `public Date(int M, int D, int Y)` constructor and the `SetDate` method. What should each of these be doing? Also, why am I being instructed to use integer variables M, D, Y when I am also being told to declare Month, Day, and Year above? Any insight that might aid me in understanding how to use this Constructer and how it relates and differs in function from the `SetDate` method would be greatly appreciated.

```
 //Create a Date Class
 //This class holds:
private int Month;
private int Day;
private int Year;
    //Include the following constructors/methods. Include others/more if you 
    //need them.

    // Sets date to 1/1/1900
public Date()

    // Sets date to user’s input.
    // Checks to see the date is valid
    // If it isn’t valid, print message and set date to 1/1/1900
public Date(int M, int D, int Y)

     // Sets date to user’s input.
     // Checks to see the date is valid
     // If it isn’t valid, print message and set date to 1/1/1900
public Boolean SetDate(int M, int D, int Y)ere
```

//******************************************************************************

```
class Date
{
    private int Month;
    private int Day;
    private int Year;

    // Sets date to 1/1/1900
    public Date()
    {
        Month = 1;
        Day = 1;
        Year = 1900;
    }

    public Date(int M, int D, int Y)
    {
        Month = M;
        Day = D;
        Year = Y;
    }

    public Boolean SetDate(int M, int D, int Y)
    {

        int valDate = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("You will be prompted to enter three(3) numbers to represent a month, " +
            "day, and year. Only dates between 1/1/1900 and 12/31/2100 are valid.");

        Console.WriteLine("");

        while (valDate < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number for the month.");
            M = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number for the day.");
            D = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number for the year.");
            Y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("");

            ValidateDate();

            if (ValidateDate())
            {
                DisplayDate();
                valDate++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid date.");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Month = 1;
                Day = 1;
                Year = 1900;
                return false;
            }


        }
        return false;
    }
        // Determines if date is valid.
    public Boolean ValidateDate()
    {
        ValidateMonth();
        ValidateDay();
        ValidateYear();

        if (ValidateMonth() && ValidateDay() && ValidateYear())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
        // Determines if month is valid.
    public Boolean ValidateMonth()
    {
        if (Month >= 1 && Month <= 12)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
        // Determines if year is valid.
    public Boolean ValidateYear()
    {
        if(Year >= 1900 && Year <= 2100)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
        // Determines if day is valid
    public Boolean ValidateDay()
    {
        IsLeapYear();

        if(Month == 1 || Month == 3 || Month == 5 || Month == 7 || Month == 8 || Month == 10 || Month == 12)
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 31)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 4 || Month == 6 || Month == 9 || Month == 11)
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 30)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear())
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 29)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 2 && !IsLeapYear())
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 28)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Determine if year is a leap year
    public Boolean IsLeapYear()
    {
        if ((Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0) || (Year % 400 == 0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

        // Print date to screen in format M/D/Y
    public void DisplayDate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ShowDate());
    }

    public String ShowDate()
    {
        StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} / {1} / {2}", Month, Day, Year);
        return (myStringBuilder.ToString());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Date NewDate = new Date();
        NewDate.Date();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've been asked to create a method and a constructor that are doing the same thing.  The simple thing to do in this case is to have the constructor call the method.

The only comment I would make about your code is that the problem statement you showed did not require the input to be gathered in the SetDate method.  Given the statement it seems like the input from the user would be gathered outside your class.

I don't know what your requirements are for the failure message.  That might make sense in it's own method as well.

Here is an example:

```
public class Date
{
    private int Month;
    private int Day;
    private int Year;

    public Date()
    {
        SetDefaultDate();
    }

    public Date(int M, int D, int Y)
    {
        SetDate(M, D, Y);
    }

    public void SetDate(int M, int D, int Y)
    {
        if (IsValidDate(M, D, Y))
        {
            Month = M;
            Day = D;
            Year = Y;
        }
        else
        {
            SetDefaultDate();
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidDate(int M, int D, int Y)
    {
        // validation logic.. return true if all parameters result in valid date
        // false if they do not.  If it is an invalid date print the failure message.

        return true;
    }

    private void SetDefaultDate()
    {
        Month = 1;
        Day = 1;
        Year = 1900;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some real application using date then i'd suggesting taking look at the DateTime struct in System namespace. That has [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) function which will return you true or false whether if the input was valid or not.

However it seems like you're doing some programming exercise so in that case my answer would be: It's not very good to have arguments in constructor which could lead to an invalid object - in your case invalid date. That's because once calling the constructor you will have an object in one way or another, except if you throw exception in constructor. Yet if you still want to have it like that then you need to have a property or public variable called "IsValid" in the class/struct which tells if valid date was given with constructor.
Nicer option is follow the DateTime approach - have a public static function which return valid Date object. Like this:

```
public bool TryParse(int m, int d, int y, out Date date)
{
   // validate

   // if valid then return Date object like that:
   date = new Date()
   {
      Month = m,
      Day = d,
      Year = y
   };
   return true;

   // Or like that:
   date = new Date(m, d, y);
   return true;

   // if not valid then return null (because have to return something)
   date = null;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: This is very good information, thank you. But, for the exercise I am doing, I am required to use the constructors or methods listed. I am unsure what to put in the `public Date(int M, int D, int Y)` constructor because, based on the instructions, it looks to me like it does the exact same thing as the `SetDate` method. Again both of these objects are required for the program.